# Sending e-mail with attachment to gmail never gets received, using phpmailer

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

Something weird is going on when i'm trying to send an e-mail with attachment to gmail, using phpmailer.
Sometimes the email received after a delay of 5 minutes and sometimes it is never received. From phpmailer debugger i get that the email is actually sended, so i assume it has something to do with the attachment getting blocked by gmail.

The attachment is a zip file containing only .jpg and .pdf files.

If i remove the `addAttachment('path/to/file')` everything works fine.

The weird thing is that sometimes, even with the attachment, the email received immediately and other times the email never gets received.

Here is the code

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'my_host';
$mail->Port = 'my_port';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'my_username@domain.com';
$mail->Password = 'my_password';
$mail->setFrom('my_username@domain.com', 'my_username@domain.com');
$mail->addAddress('test@gmail.com', 'test@gmail.com');
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->msgHTML($msg);
$mail->AltBody = $subject;
$mail->addAttachment($zipfilename);

if($mail->send()){
    echo "ok";
}else{
    echo "error";
}
```

I don't have any clue why this is happening so any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:
I found out that with two changes everything works fine.
The changes are the setting
`$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'`
and i had a path like this `./path/to/file` and changed it to 'path/to/file'.

Comment: If gmail bounces it you should get a error response back.    Is it always the same file and the same pdf or are they vastly different?  E..g. size matters ..

Comment: In what section should i get an error? Because even with `SMTPDebug = 2` i get no error. The size is never above 1 MB and the only files included in the zip file are .jpg and .pdf. Does the name of the file have any relation with the message getting delayed or blocked?

Comment: I just tried the `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` and it seems to be working for now for some reason.

Comment: Did you look into the spam folder of gmail?

Comment: Yes, and i tried some other gmail accounts aswell to see the behavior and it seems to be as weird as in my original address. But for now the tls setting seems to work. I will edit the question if that was the problem. In any case thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you really sending to 'test@gmail.com'? I suspect not, but is it a gmail account?  I am confronting this pdf issue also - error message states blocked content (!! it's a pdf) `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls` does not do the trick form me. Was this happening to non-gmail accounts?

Comment: Hello. I am using a valid gmail. Generally, other mail servers received the mail normally. Try to use a full path on addAttachment. Also check SSL/TLS settings and the port you are using. You can also try to set SMTPSecure to SSL instead of tls.